# How to print Myanmar Unicode in Zebra with using ZPL language?

Tags: printing, zpl

Everybody

How to print myanmar unicode(myanmar3.TTF)  on zebra printer with using zpl language?

I tried to test so many times. i still got problems with zpl code.
here, my code:

ï»¿^XA^LRN^CI0^XZ

^XA^CWP,E:MYANMAR3.TTF ^FS

^XZ

^XA

^FO10,50^CI28^APN,30,30^FDZebra Technologies^FS

^FO10,100^CI14^APN,30,30^FD- CI 14:ရသာမွန်^FS

^FO010,150^CI33^APN,40,40^FD- CI 33:ရသာမွန် ^FS

^FO010,200^CI34^APN,40,40^FD- CI 34:ရသာမွန် ^FS

^FO010,250^CI35^APN,40,40^FD- CI 35:ရသာမွန် ^FS

^FO010,300^CI36^AMN,40,40^FD- CI 36:ရသာမွန် ^FS

^PA1,1,1,1^FS ^FX Enables Advanced Text ^FS

^FO010,350^CI28^AMN,40,40^FD- CI31:ရသာမွန် ^FS

^PQ1
^XZ

[This is my printing out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUt0S.png)

Answer (score 1):

How do you communicate with your Zebra printer?
You should be ensured that you send Unicode-encoded text to printer.

For example, if you open Zebra Setup Utilites (Open Communication With Printer) and copy-paste ZPL text to it - it will **NOT** work.

Try create Unicode encoded text file in your text editor, save it, and then send it to the printer via printer driver (right click on printer -> Print setup -> Tools -> Send file action command)

Also, try to use the `^CI` command (see ZPL docs) *at the beginnig* of the label (just after `^XA`, before any other command).
For example, `^CI28` works for UTF-8 encoded texts.
You may try `^CI29` or `^CI30` for UTF-16.

Comment: OK, I already done it, Thanks for your answer.I can print it with Myanmar Font, how about chinese font?